# NgRx selector is returning the Store object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to integrate NgRx with my Angular app but I'm having some trouble. I've defined an action, reducer and selector but I'm not getting the data I'm expecting.

I define an action `getReceipts`:

```
// file-state.actions.ts

export const getReceipts = createAction(
  '[Receipt] Get receipt',
  (receipts: Receipt[]) => ({ receipts })
);
```

A reducer `receiptReducer`, which should be called by the `getReceipts` action:

```
// file-state.reducers.ts

const initialState: ReadonlyArray<Receipt> = [
  {merchant_name: 'default'}
];

export const receiptReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ReceiptActions.getReceipts, (state, { receipts }) => [...receipts]),
)
```

And a selector to get the data from the store:

```
// file-state.selector.ts

export const selectReceipts = createSelector(
  (state: AppState) => state.receipts,
  (receipts: Receipt[]) => receipts
);
```

And finally in my Angular component:

```
export class ViewFilesComponent implements OnInit {
  // receipts$: Observable<Receipt[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    console.log(this.store.pipe(select(selectReceipts)))
    console.log(this.store.dispatch(getReceipts([])))
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

The dispatch is returning an undefined object, which is fine because an action returns void. So I think I need to call the `selectReceipts` selector, but that returns the Store object:

[image]

Comment: this.store.pipe(select(selectReceipts)) - this return Observable, you need to subscribe for it.

Comment: Stupid me, I tried to the a `.then` but that's for async call, not Observeables. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

My advice here below,
I would not use an action to get a part of the application state,
in your component you can use the observable given by store.select,
passing the reducer as argument.

You should use an action, for example, when you need to make an http call.
Also the state should be a simple object.

Since my application is composed by several feature modules,
I usually use injectionTokens to get a reducer inside a component,
I skipped that part in this example.

file: store/reducer/index.reducer.ts

```
export interface State {
  receipts: Array<Receipt>
}

export const initialState: State = {
  receipts: []
}

const reducerDefinition = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(fromAction.someAction, (state, { someValue}) => ({
    ...state, 
    someProp: someValue
  }))
)

export function reducer(state, action) {
  return reducerDefinition(state, action)
}

export const getReceipts = (state: State) => state.receipts
```

In your component you can subscribe to the getReceipts$ observable

```
this.getReceipts$ = this.store.select(getReceipts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Piyush's answer helped me the best. I created a class member `receipts$` and gave it a Observable of type `[]`. Then in the constructor I passed the returned observable from the NgRx store `this.store.pipe(select(selectReceipts)` in it. Then in the html I did:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let receipt of receipts$ | async; index as i">
    <p>
      {{i}}: {{receipt.merchant_name}}
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```